# How to access local & session storage variable from HTML to Django and how to get in my app views.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Django version is - 1.10.5 Python 2.7.10

I'm beginner in Django. Assistance required.

What i have done so far:-

1) I have already passing successfully local or session variables between HTML pages.

My Questions are:-

1) Do i need to specify anything in HTML or Django to access local or session storage variables?

2) How do i get that local or session variables in my views.py?

3) Without models can i do this? because i don't want anything to store in database.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you mean, for example, like for the currently logged in User?

Comment: Yes, but my application doesn't have any login page or user database.               It has one urlbox in first page and check box in second page.                                                        So i concatenate those input and i will form a new string in third page.                   So i need to get that third page session variable in my views.py.

Comment: Session storage and local storage store data in your browser. There is no way Django can access that data unless you explicitly pass it to the backend.

Comment: @knbk, so i have to create model for each and every html page ?

Comment: I didn't say anything about a model. You need to pass the data to your view, not necessarily to the database.

Comment: @knbk, that's my requirement, how to pass that data to views. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is client storage in your browser. Your *.py files will be executed in server. So you can not access them directly. You can save them as cookie, or put them to server via ajax request.